# Consuming Entity Framework entities in a client application that are exposed using a WCF services

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, ria

I have a DAL where I have Entity Framework to expose entities. These entities are used in a WCF Service project and exposed to the client.

I consume these entities in the Silverlight web project via service reference. Then I am using a RIA domain service for code sharing. But I get the following error while trying to load operation:

```
DomainContext context= new DomainContext();
LoadOperation<Genre> lo = context.Load<Genre>(context.GetGenres());
```

GetGenres() is a Domain Service operation where it loads all Genres.

```
    [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<Genre> GetGenres()
    {
        return proxy.GetGenres();  //proxy is wcf proxy.
    }
```

This Query returns a List. Where Genre is the DataContract i
got from the WCFServiceReference.

Actual Error:

> The type 'SL.Web.ServiceReference.Genre' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load(System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'SL.Web.ChinookServiceReference.Genre'                      to
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity'.

Question is:

Can I do this way or should I have a custom class in Silverlight that maps to the WCF service datacontract and share the custom entity between the Silverlight client and Web project?

Is there a way to share entities from a service reference between Web and client using a DomainService??

Comment: Are you exposing GetGenres as a DomainService, or just a plain WCF service?

Comment: Domain Service operation only.

Comment: Is GetGenres() being interpreted as a Query?  I've never tried to return a list from a DomainService -- always either IEnumerable<Entity> or IQueryable<Entity>.  Maybe GetGenres() is being generated as an Invoke instead of a Query.

Comment: Pasted my DomainServiceOperation code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have GetGenres marked as an Invoke operation.  If you mark it as a query operation and rebuild, I think that you will be in good shape.

Comment: when i changed to [Query] i got some other exception. 
 Entity 'SL.Web.ChinookServiceReference.Genre' has a property 'ExtensionData' with an unsupported type.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere (believe it or not!)  Does that Genre class have some sort of complex type or object member?  Can you post the class definition for Genre?  Also, maybe this post will help: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/139977.aspx/1